# Error when calling createDefaultLayers() in HERE API

Tags: here-api

EDIT: Is there anywhere to get an un-minified version of the Here-api to use when debugging? It's impossible for me to figure out what 'v' is and why it may be undefined.

We're using the HERE API both from our website where it works flawlessly and our old RDP C++ application which runs a similar webpage in an embedded IE window. It should be using a stripped version of IE11 I believe.

We recently upgraded to the new HERE API after routing stopped working in the old one, and it worked for a while but a while ago it suddenly didn't. And no one can recall making any changes that could affect this.

I have narrowed it down to a single line of code where it crashes. (`platform` is already defined in the scope through our geo-service script, the same one being used for the web that works)

```
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
```

This is an initialization of the map layers that is required for the maps to work, but we simply can't perform this action through this embedded browser window even though we run almost identical code on the web.

We receive two error messages of:

```
'v' is undefined
```

With a reference to some dynamically generated eval code.

This is the only lead I've managed to dig up, it's not much but I'm hoping someone else has encountered a similar issue and can point me in the right direction what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was totally self inflicted...
When we implemented the solution there was an issue in the core js file from Here which made it not work in our servers due to some path being wrong. To fix this we had changed the path so it worked and then hosted our own version of the core file.

This worked great, until Here put up a new minor release which is automatically distributed through the same content link as before. This meant the minified files were no longer in sync with the variable names, thus causing v to never be defined where it should, since in our file it was probably named something else.

It was only by chance I noticed that the core js was side-loaded like that, I was looking in the completely opposite direction the entire time and didn't even consider the loading might've been tinkered with.